# How do I use a map as a background?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I would like to do something somewhat similar to Foursqure.com. They're using a map of your current location as a background. I'm using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) for my map and I have the map showing up. I thought if I just put something like:

```
<div id="map">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</div>
```

Then Welcome! would get overlayed on the map. However, I am naive and this does not work. Can anyone suggest a way in which I can do this?

**EDIT:**
Here is some of my custom CSS. I'm using Twitter bootstrap, so that will play into it as well. The html is pretty much exactly what I've shown here.

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.leaflet-container {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting z-index.

Comment: Yeah, z-index on h1 doesn't work, and z-index on the map div itself doesn't work either and just causes the map to be unusable as all the controls fall behind everything.

Comment: Did you use non-static `position` together with `z-index`? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: feed us with some more code or the css that's used for map..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Leaflet blows out any content inside of the `<div>` that you give it.  Leaflet expects an empty `<div>`.

Just z-index the map below the rest of your content, which should be a sibling of the map element, not a child.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/tnaVa/)

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. I've placed all of my contents inside a dive and am overlapping it onto the map. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#map{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:0;
}
```

Any other content that goes should be give z-index higher than 0

Comment: Ah I was really hoping that would work, but unfortunately it's a no-go.

Comment: Then what you describe is not enough to understand what you really want or what your problems is.

Answer (score 2):

```
 z-index: -1;
```

try this instead of 0

sorry this wont work either as you are having header inside map...
you will have to restructure your html..

Answer (score 1):

Put two divs as siblings while keeping the map as the second sibling. Both should have an absolute position.

In the HTML code:

```
<div class="nxt-content">test</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

In the CSS code:

```
#map {
   z-index: 0 !important;
   position: absolute;
   height: calc(100% - 56px);
   width: calc(100% - 15rem);
}

.nxt-content {
  z-index: 1 !important;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: yellow;
}
```